# Symfony get form data in controller

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.1

I have this view:

```
//login.html.twig

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>MY APP</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="{{ path('conection') }}" method="post" name="formulario_login">
        <label for="username">User:</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username|default('') }}" />
        <br />
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" />
        <br />
        <input type="checkbox" id="remember_me" name="_remember_me"/>
        <label for="remember_me">Remember me</label>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

In my routing file:

```
conection:
pattern:  /conection
defaults: { _controller: UserBundle:Default:conection}
```

And my controller

```
<?php

namespace myApp\UserBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    //some other action functions

    public function conectionAction(){

    }
}
```

My question is how do I get in the controller the values of user and password fields to work with them?I have search but I don´t see a clear solution.

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#handling-form-submissions

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this, by way of example and using Symfony2.8

**View:**

```
  <form action="{{ path('connection') }}" method="post" name="formulario_login">
        <label for="username">User:</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="" />
        <br />
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" />
        <br />
        <input type="checkbox" id="remember_me" name="_remember_me"/>
        <label for="remember_me">Remember me</label>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" />
    </form>
```

**Controller:**

```
public function connectionAction(Request $request) {
    $username = $request->request->get('_username');
    $password = $request->request->get('_password');
     ....
}
```

Other way to get parameters, as you can see the naming is not all that intuitive:

```
 // $_GET parameters
$request->query->get('name');

// $_POST parameters
$request->request->get('name');
```

Comment: Thanks,now I get my variables in the controller, as you say,the query->get() method needs the name of the field,not the id.

Comment: Yes @SensacionRC, in the example you will get the name of the fields "_username" and "_password", not the ID, other way and best practice to build form is http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/forms.html

Answer (score 5):

You should pass the Request object to the action method then deal with it:

```
public function conectionAction(Request $request){
    if ($request->getMethod() == Request::METHOD_POST){
        $user = $request->request->get('user');
        $password = $request->request->get('password');
    }
}
```

However I suggest you to use the [Symfony Form Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html) to dial with this situation.