# Symfony get Data from form

Tags: php, symfony

I want to get Data in my form but it's return null for the select box who contains a forgein key of my entities and for my datetime, I have an error

```
Fatal Error: Call to a member function format() on null
```

I tried to getdata like this

```
$client = $form['id']['client']->getData();
```

this is a forgein key for my entity class and it in a select box, it's return null when I select option in select box, the name of select box is `name = "appbundle_fournir[id][client]"`

```
$date = $form['date']->getData()->format('d-m-Y');
```

for my datetime, I do something like that but it return an error I mention on top.

How can I do it properly to get my Data, thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get form values in Symfony2 controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8987418/how-to-get-form-values-in-symfony2-controller)

Comment: What is `$form`?

Comment: check this out
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42817800/symfony-get-form-data-in-controller

Answer (score 1):

To get data from a form in the newest Symfony versions you use the following code:

```
$data = $form->getData();

$date = $data->getDate();
$name = $data->getName();
```

Note that this requires mapped entities with getters and setters like getDate() and getName()

(the syntax for this has changed in the newer Symfony versions)