# How can I pass a single parameter from $_POST?

Tags: symfony, controller, twig

I am trying to input some data (idUser + idEvaluation) into a variable ($value) in my controller using a $_POST from twig. I am sorry if I use wrong terms - I am totally new in informatics...

When I dump the $value I can see that idUser and idEvaluation are inside .

Then, my goal is to put these retrieved data into a table in a database (to update my database)

For that I create an object of the target table in the database (the one I want to update) and I pass my $value for each item in the columnn (Evaluation or User) I would like to set.

My question is: how can I pass a SINGLE parameter for each field, e.g. right now I pass always two parameters (idUser + idEvaluation) at once and there's no difference between setIdEvaluation and setIdUser - they both contain idUser + idEvaluation. While I would  like to have only (idUser) in setIdUser and only (idEvaluation) in setIdEvaluation.

(i did my best to explain my question - sorry if I made it a bit messy, I will do my best to clarify the details if necessary)

Thank you!

```
//In my controller    

$value = $_POST;     // what I receive from twig 


    $EvalUser = new EvaluationUser();  // I create and object of the table in database that I want to update

    $EvalUser->setIdEvaluation($value); // here I (am trying to) put received data into a IdEvaluation 
    $EvalUser->setIdUser($value);   // here I (am trying to) put received data into a IdUser

    dump($EvalUser);     // I dump a variable and I have IdEvaluation and IdUser in both cases (which is normal, of course)
```

Comment: I removed the php tag because of terrible answers you are getting. In Symfony you never access $_POST variable directly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony get form data in controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42817800/symfony-get-form-data-in-controller)

Answer (score 0):

Your `$_POST` variable is an array. You can access the individual values by telling the array what key you want. So in your case you want `$_POST['idUser']` and `$_POST['idEvaluation']`

Or for the full code:

```
$EvalUser = new EvaluationUser();  

$EvalUser->setIdEvaluation($_POST['idEvaluation']); 
$EvalUser->setIdUser($_POST['idUser']);  

var_dump($EvalUser);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you can get idEvaluation and idUser like that :

```
 public function getuserInfoAction(Request $request) {

  $idEvaluation = $request->request->idEvaluation;
  $iduser = $request->request->idUser;

  $EvalUser = new EvaluationUser();  

 $EvalUser->setIdEvaluation($idEvaluation ); 
 $EvalUser->setIdUser($iduser);  

 var_dump($EvalUser);
```

}